# Javascript: IE Full height

Tags: javascript, lightbox, lightbox2

I have the following code to calculate the window width for a lightbox plugin from [this site](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/).

```
     * getPageSize() by quirksmode.com
     *
     * @return Array Return an array with page width, height and window width, height
     */
    function ___getPageSize() {
        var xScroll, yScroll;
        if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY) {  
            xScroll = window.innerWidth + window.scrollMaxX;
            yScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
        } else if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight){ // all but Explorer Mac
            xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
            yScroll = document.body.scrollHeight;
        } else { // Explorer Mac...would also work in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla and Safari
            xScroll = document.body.offsetWidth;
            yScroll = document.body.offsetHeight;
        }
        var windowWidth, windowHeight;
        if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
            if(document.documentElement.clientWidth){
                windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; 
            } else {
                windowWidth = self.innerWidth;
            }
            windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
        } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
            windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
            windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        }   
        // for small pages with total height less then height of the viewport
        if(yScroll < windowHeight){
            pageHeight = windowHeight;
        } else { 
            pageHeight = yScroll;
        }
        // for small pages with total width less then width of the viewport
        if(xScroll < windowWidth){  
            pageWidth = xScroll;        
        } else {
            pageWidth = windowWidth;
        }
        arrayPageSize = new Array(pageWidth,pageHeight,windowWidth,windowHeight);
        return arrayPageSize;
    };
```

I noticed that in Internet Explorer 9, when I click on an image and the Lightbox plugin activates, the transparent back overlay only covers the VIEWABLE height and not the full height.

[image]

This creates a problem because, if I have another image with the modified Lightbox plugin and click below the transparent overlay, it opens another empty lightbox window at the top of the page and cannot be closed.

It works fine in Chrome, and Firefox.

Comment: have actually tried achieving this without javascript and only with CSS?

Comment: I think IE uses document.documentElement.offsetWidth

Comment: @redconservatory: I meant **height** not width. Either way, I tried `document.documentElement.offsetHeight` in the console and it returned the visible height.

Comment: Hm I think for a lightbox the transparent black overlay usually is set to cover the VIEWABLE height, but the css for that overlay should be position: fixed instead of something else. If not the overlay won't scroll properly as you go down the page.

Comment: I set `#jquery-overlay` css property `position` to `fixed` and it seemed to have worked on my page, but on another shorter page the overlay appears underneath the lightbox image.